# when user enters anything in Korean into the input tag and shifts the focus to any other part of the screen, the focus is shifted back to the input

Tags: html, css

[`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/ruskho0n/nsgu5v8j/1/)
steps to reproduce :
write Korean in the input box
scroll down till the input box is hidden
Click any where on the screen

Expected: input box will come into focus at (Korean text)

when the user types in Korean in the input box .and if we move the input box out of frame. and click anywhere else .input box will keep in frame .this is not reproducible in mac. `

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Typing into an input box, then clicking away on the screen so that it loses focus should not make the input box scroll back into view; at least that's never how it's worked for me on any of my OS/browser combinations. The "expected" outcome from your question seems wrong to me, are you sure you've phrased the question correctly?

Comment: you better find a better way to explain your problem, because I didn't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the focus to be added back to the input field even on clicking anywhere on the screen, use `focus-me="1"` (I took 1 as an example, you can use any number).

If you don't want the focus to be added back to the input field, you can use `$removeAttribute('focus-me')` or remove the autofocus element using your `.ts` file